# JAR File Creation in JDK 11 and JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

As we already know up to JDK-10 JavaFX used to be a part of JDK but with the release of JDK-11, JavaFX is to be included separately .

For doing that we need  to provide **VM argument** for JavaFX like this:-

```
--module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Up to this point every thing is ok but when we are finally creating a JAR file for distribution then a message is appearing like this:

> VM arguments will not be part of the runnable JAR. Arguments can be passed on the command line when launching the JAR

[image: screenshot]

Therefore now JAR file is not able to open the application.

Now please help me by suggesting some way out so that user can open application just by clicking on JAR icon as it used to be earlier.

**EDIT**

After applying the solution provided by 
[openjfx.io](http://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular) (section non-modular projects), I am able to generate a Standalone Jar File with JavaFX.

Now I want to add some local dependencies like `pdfbox` and `Sqlite`:

```
sqlite =C:\sqlite-jdbc-3.6.20.1.jar 
pdfbox=C:\pdfbox-app-2.0.10.jar
```

I am doing following steps:

**Step-1**

```
cd eclipse-workspace2018\test101
```

**Step-2**

```
set PATH_TO_FX="C:\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib"
```

**Step-3**

```
dir /s /b src\*.java > sources.txt & \
    javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules=javafx.controls \
    -d out @sources.txt & del sources.txt
```

**Step-4**

```
cd out & jar xf "%PATH_TO_FX%\javafx.base.jar" & \
    jar xf "%PATH_TO_FX%\javafx.graphics.jar" & \
    jar xf "%PATH_TO_FX%\javafx.controls.jar" & \
    cd .. 
copy "%PATH_TO_FX%\..\bin\prism*.dll" out & \
    copy "%PATH_TO_FX%\..\bin\javafx*.dll" out & \
    copy "%PATH_TO_FX%\..\bin\glass.dll" out & \
    copy "%PATH_TO_FX%\..\bin\decora_sse.dll" out 
del out\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF & del out\module-info.class 
mkdir libs 
jar --create --file=libs/index101.jar \
    --main-class=test101.Launcher -C out . 
java -jar libs\index101.jar
```

Kindly modify my steps for adding above mentioned two dependencies pdfBox & sqlite.

Comment: Add those arguments while executing the jar as well.

Comment: please elaborate **executing the jar **

Comment: do you mean  at the time of  launch   ?                                                 if yes  please modify my code  which is given below:-                                                                                              
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     
     
        launch(args);
    }

Comment: Yes, I meant at the time of running the jar you can add the similar VM args and give it a try. Try for example executing from command line.

Comment: Thank U but still problem is that since javaFx-jdk is not a part of JRE and not becoming part of JAR that is finally generated . Therefore end users of application will not be able to run the application unless they have a copy of javaFx-jdk in their system . Moreover running though command like by passing additional parameter is ok for developer but not for user. please help

Comment: You can't generate a fat-jar that includes JavaFX libraries from Eclipse (`export -> runnable jar`) directly as far as I know. However you can do it from command line (see https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular, section `non-modular projects`), but it is not the best solution. With Maven or Gradle build tools is easier.

Comment: Thank U ,this worked but one more question is that method specified in  openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular, section non-modular projects is for those projects which are using javaFx only .   How to include additional external JAR Library like PdfBox ,sqlite  etc

Comment: You can add other dependencies to the fat jar, of course, using the same approach. If you already have those jars, add them like instructed for the JavaFX ones. Of course, using Maven/Gradle build tools and their plugins will simplify the problem.

Comment: unrelated to your problem: PDFBox is at 2.0.13 now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a word of advice: Creating fat jars on command line is not advised at all. It is a manual process that should be avoided. You should try Maven or Gradle and the existing plugins for this task, in case you still need a fat jar. You should try to create a modular project, instead, and create a custom image with `jlink` that you can distribute for a given platform.

Second, if you still want to do a fat jar manually, you should understand the above steps, in order to be able to modify them according to your needs. Basically the main idea of a fat jar is a single project with all the *.class files (and other resources) from all the possible dependencies, not only those from your source code. The tutorial at openjfx.io just mentions the case of JavaFX dependencies.

So if you have extra dependencies, the idea is to extract the content of their jars, in the same way you extract the JavaFX jars. See [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jar.html#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867) command options like `xf`.

That is done in the step 3:

```
cd out & jar xf "%PATH_TO_FX%\javafx.base.jar" & \
    jar xf "%PATH_TO_FX%\javafx.graphics.jar" & \
    jar xf "%PATH_TO_FX%\javafx.controls.jar" & \
    cd ..
```

You can modify that step with your existing jars:

```
cd out & jar xf "%PATH_TO_FX%\javafx.base.jar" & \
    jar xf "%PATH_TO_FX%\javafx.graphics.jar" & \
    jar xf "%PATH_TO_FX%\javafx.controls.jar" & \
    jar xf "C:\sqlite-jdbc-3.6.20.1.jar" & \
    jar xf "C:\pdfbox-app-2.0.10.jar" & \
    cd ..
```

Then you can proceed with the rest of the steps in the same way.

Note that while this might work, those third party jars might have other dependencies as well (see their pom.xml for that). If that's the case, you will need to download them manually, and add them to the fat jar in the same way. Should you use Maven or Gradle, they will do it automatically for you.

As mentioned before, this is not advised at all.

Comment: Thank You Sir, I have understood that I need to learn  Maven to solve my problem in a proper manner.